# Does Tycho support JUnit @Category?

Tags: tycho

The Maven surefire plugin supports JUnit @Category (as well as TestNG groups) with the "groups" configuration item.
Does this feature also supported by the "tycho-surefire" plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

The bug [Bug386964](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=386964) is marked as resolved in tycho 0.25.0 but tycho 0.25.0 is not yet published.

Answer (score 1):

> The Maven surefire plugin supports JUnit @Category (as well as TestNG groups) with the "groups" configuration item. Does this feature also supported by the "tycho-surefire" plugin ?

Tycho supports **JUnit categories** since **version 0.25** (release on 15 April 2016). See the [release notes](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Release_Notes/0.25#Test_Execution).

Tycho will support **TestNG groups** with **version 0.26** (*estimated* release date: 19 August 2016). See the [release notes](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Release_Notes/0.26) on how to [use groups with Tycho](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Release_Notes/0.26#Using_Groups).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the current version of tycho (0.19) is still based on surefire 2.10, and support for JUnit categories has only be added to surefire 2.11 (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-329). Too bad ! :-(

Comment: This is the bug for fixing this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=386481